# Is there a French equivalent to the English expression "hot potato"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

A definition from the [Oxford Dictionary of Phrase and Fable](https://books.google.com/books?id=Urg3hNc4tu0C&pg=PT815&lpg=PT815&dq=a%20controversial%20issue%20or%20situation%20that%20is%20awkward%20or%20unpleasant%20to%20deal%20with&source=bl&ots=7m2aFhzVLI&sig=H6gcKe8W0o4Ta7s1gxQ8aCuicQs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAGoVChMIxIjlirmTxwIVwY0NCh2zhgDG) is

> "a controversial issue or situation that is awkward or unpleasant to deal with"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Traduction

L'expression « [patate chaude](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/patate_chaude) » est passée au français. La traduction est littérale et le sens est conservé.

La [définition du Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/patate_chaude) correspond à celle donnée par Oxford :

> Chose dont personne ne veut s’occuper.

Concrètement, cette expression est utilisée pour désigner un sujet pour lequel différents intervenants cherchent à se renvoyer la responsabilité afin de ne pas avoir à le gérer personnellement.

---

The expression has passed into French and can be translated as "*patate chaude*". The translation is literal and the meaning is conserved (*patate* is a common word for *potato*, though the correct phrase is *pomme de terre*).

#### Propositions d'équivalents

[cl-r](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/848/cl-r) suggère le synonyme suivant :

> Refiler le bébé

[L'idée derrière cette expression](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-synonymes/refiler%20le%20b%C3%A9b%C3%A9) est assez proche de celle « [refiler la patate chaude](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-synonymes/refiler%20la%20patate%20chaude) ». Il y a cependant une nuance : tout le monde se brûle les doigts lorsque la pomme de terre est chaude et essaie de la passer à son voisin. Dans le cas de « refiler le bébé », on sait qu'un intervenant se débarrasse de la tâche, sans savoir si le suivant fera de même ou nom.

Ainsi que le fait remarquer [Random](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/7321/random), l'expression peut être trompeuse : on parle souvent de « son bébé » pour une œuvre à laquelle on a consacré du temps et qui a par conséquent de l'importance à nos yeux et nous fait éprouver un sentiment de fierté. Toutefois, en conjugaison avec le verbe « refiler », [celui-ci prend une connotation négative de problème](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/refiler_le_b%C3%A9b%C3%A9). On peut penser à un bébé qui hurle et dont on est heureux de le confier à un autre. Si l'on parle de laisser à un autre le soin de s'occuper de l'œuvre dont on est fier, le mot qui me vient à l'esprit est « confier ». « Je te confie mon bébé » (le possessif est souvent de mise, et le verbe traduit la *confiance* : il nous est trop cher pour le laisser à n'importe qui).

Comment: Merci! Est-ce qu'il existe des autres expressions avec le même sens qui ne sont pas anglaises en origine ?

Comment: J'ai essayé de trouver d'autres exemples au moment d'écrire la réponse mais rien ne m'est venu à l'esprit. On peut parler d'un « sujet brûlant », mais cela peut tout aussi bien être compris comme un point d'actualité déchaînant les passions...

Comment: @cl-r Pour moi, "refiler le bébé" est quelque chose de positif, contrairement à la "patate chaude". Quand quelqu'un "refile le bébé", c'est quelque chose sur laquelle la personne a passé beaucoup de temps et en a pris soin.

Comment: @Random Quand on parle de son « bébé », c'est effectivement le cas. Lorsque c'est en conjonction avec « refiler », le sens devient négatif (imaginer un enfant qui hurle et dont on est heureux de le confier à un autre). Lorsque je parle de laisser mon œuvre au soin d'autres, je parle de le « confier » (j'en ai pris soin, je fais _confiance_ au suivant pour en faire autant).

Comment: @Random Je ne serais pas aussi catégorique pour l'aspect positif de "refiler le bébé", qui est malgré tout souvent employé pour décrire la transmission d'une lourde responsabilité... de mon point de vue l'ensemble de la réponse de Chop est excellent (+1).

Comment: L'explication me va, en effet :)

Comment: J'ai déjà entendu le très vulgaire "baton merdeux"

Comment: @LaurentS. [La signification](https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/bâton_merdeux) n'est pas la même. Wiktionnaire parle d'une personne que l'on ne sait pas comment aborder. J'imagine que cela peut s'étendre au-delà du personnel. Je l'avais compris différemment : on pense avoir un bout de bois jusqu'au moment où on le prend en main. Il est souvent alors trop tard pour le passer à un autre. La patate chaude met vraiment l'emphase sur le fait que je sujet brûle les doigts et que personne ne veut y toucher. Le bâton merdeux signifie simplement qu'il est inabordable ou piège.

Answer (score 1):

Le jeu est quelque peu désuet, mais l'image toujours aussi claire : "repasser le mistigri".
Dans ce jeu de cartes (mistigri des familles), chacun doit composer des paires en piochant dans le jeu de l'un de ses adversaires. Comme on en a retiré une (non connue) avant le début de la partie, il y a toujours quelqu'un qui a en main la carte perdante (le mistigri), qu'il faut identifier puis tenter de repasser à quelqu'un. Le perdant est celui qui se retrouve le dernier avec cette carte en main.Voir illustration dans http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mistigri

Cela traduit assez finement la "patate chaude", mélange d'adresse et d'opportunisme propre à ce jeu...